# I got stuck on Multiple Select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got stuck on this because I have a Multiple select like this

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
 SELECT CASE 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%อย.%' THEN  2
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%มผช%' THEN 3 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%มอก.%' THEN 4 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%ฮาลาล%' THEN 5
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%Q%' THEN 6 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%GMP%' THEN 7 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%GAP%' THEN 8 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%HACCP%' THEN 9 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%เกษตรอินทรีย์%' THEN 10 
 ELSE 1 END As ID
        , co.[grdtxtCertificationOther] AS STDName
        , co.[grdtxtCertificationNumberOther] AS STDNumber
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),
           CASE 
               WHEN LEN(co.grddatIssueDateOther) >4 
               THEN co.grddatIssueDateOther
           END,109) As SentDate  
        , dp.libtxtUserID  As ParentID
        , 1 AS Displayorder
        , 0 AS isDisable
FROM Custom.tblR_docProduct dp
INNER JOIN  [Custom].[tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther] co
ON dp.Id = co._Parent) t
WHERE NOT t.SentDate IS NULL
AND NOT t.STDName IS NULL
AND NOT t.STDNumber IS NULL
```

I need them to change a value contain in STDName that's ID is 2-9 to NULL

but I can't use a expression before i've named them as t 
how can i add more if clause or case ?

I need to add a expression like this

```
if t.id <> 1 then t.STDName = NULL
```

Comment: Your query appears to be incomplete. Please check that you've posted the whole thing.

Comment: I posted the whole thing that contain every line of my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you construct your query.

```
SELECT star
     , is
     , evil
     , CASE WHEN evil = 1 THEN star ELSE NULL END As we_can_refer_to_this_now
FROM   (
        SELECT star
             , is
             , CASE WHEN column = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As evil
        FROM   ...
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  evil IN (1, 0)
```

Once you have made the inner query a subquery (wrap it in brackets and give it an alias) the columns within are accessible to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to repeat the whole `CASE` again, this time when selecting `STDName`

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
 SELECT CASE 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%อย.%' THEN  2
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%มผช%' THEN 3 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%มอก.%' THEN 4 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%ฮาลาล%' THEN 5
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%Q%' THEN 6 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%GMP%' THEN 7 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%GAP%' THEN 8 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%HACCP%' THEN 9 
 WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%เกษตรอินทรีย์%' THEN 10 
 ELSE 1 END As ID,
 CASE 
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%อย.%' THEN NULL
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%มผช%' THEN NULL 
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%มอก.%' THEN NULL
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%ฮาลาล%' THEN NULL
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%Q%' THEN NULL 
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%GMP%' THEN NULL 
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%GAP%' THEN NULL
     WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%HACCP%' THEN NULL
             WHEN co.grdtxtCertificationOther LIKE '%เกษตรอินทรีย์%' THEN NULL 
     ELSE co.[grdtxtCertificationOther] 
END AS STDName
        , co.[grdtxtCertificationNumberOther] AS STDNumber
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),
           CASE 
               WHEN LEN(co.grddatIssueDateOther) >4 
               THEN co.grddatIssueDateOther
           END,109) As SentDate  
        , dp.libtxtUserID  As ParentID
        , 1 AS Displayorder
        , 0 AS isDisable
FROM Custom.tblR_docProduct dp
INNER JOIN  [Custom].[tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther] co
ON dp.Id = co._Parent) t
WHERE NOT t.SentDate IS NULL
AND NOT t.STDName IS NULL
AND NOT t.STDNumber IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your initial query:

```
SELECT
 ID,
 CASE 
  WHEN ID = 1 THEN STDName ELSE NULL END AS STDName,
 STDNumber,
 SentDate,
 ParentID,
 Displayorder,
 isDisable
FROM (_YOUR_INITIAL_QUERY_) Q1
```